# Change language of springer journal template (svjour3) to French

Tags: templates, languages, french, journal

I have to write a report in LaTeX, and it has to be done with the Springer journal template (`svjour3`).

The problem is that my report has to be in French, but I can't find how to change the language of the words that are tied to the template to French (e.g. "Keywords" to "Mots-clé", "Abstract" to "Résumé"... etc) despite the fact that the French words are present in the `svjour3.cls` file.

Comment: Well, actually you just have to add "francais" to the options while declaring the document class.

Comment: Can you make that an official answer in the big box below?

Answer (score 3):

The OP found an answer himself:

> Well, actually you just have to add `francais` to the options while declaring the document class.